# NET Core - FromForm posted Nested Object is not being sent to the Microservice as a normal List

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

So, in my controller, I have this

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExpenseSubmission([FromForm] myModel request)
```

And it is expected the info to be sent via FrontEnd from a Form, which is happening and I'm receiving all the information.

This is the append part of the List in the FrontEnd code:

```
      formdata.append("expense.procList[0].StringA", "asd");
      formdata.append("expense.procList[0].StringB", "Consulta SNS");
      formdata.append("expense.procList[0].StringC", "20");
      formdata.append("expense.procList[0].StringD", "310");
      formdata.append("expense.procList[0].StringE", "2020-10-13");
```

This model receives a List in which is working all well and I get the information, the problem is, when I sent the List to a WebService that I need to communicate with, it gives me this error:

```
Message = "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[ADV.Service.Client.IreneWS.Models.ErrorResponse]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix...
```

But whenever I change to `[FromBody]` it doesn't give me this problem...
Is my list just working like an Array or is it something that I'm missing here?
In the FrontEnd code, is it something that is wrong?

Comment: FromForm uses form application format... FromBody uses JSON

Comment: Hello Is there anything else I can help you with?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are trying to `POST` your formdata to your `Asp.net Core` controller and got a `Json` parsing error.

You are getting this error because your format for `FromForm` is not correct as you can see here in [Microsoft Official Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#sources).

As no example given in offical document so I am attaching two examples for your on both `FromForm` and `FromBody`

**FromForm Example:**

`Client Side Example:`

```
h2>From From </h2>

@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function (e) {

                data = new FormData();
                data.append("MpnID", 5);
                data.append("PartnerName", "Leandro Batista");

                $.ajax("https://localhost:44346/api/ConnectUs/FromFormExample", {
                    method: "post",
                    processData: false,
                   // contentType: false,
                    contentType: "application /x-www-url-formencoded",
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $("#MpnID").text(data.mpnID);
                        $("#PartnerName").text(data.partnerName);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}

<table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr><th>MpnID:</th><td id="MpnID"></td></tr>
    <tr><th>PartnerName:</th><td id="PartnerName"></td></tr>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

> **Note:** In case of `FromForm`  `contentType` should be `contentType: false` and
> data binding format should be like this
> `data.append("MpnID", 5); data.append("PartnerName", "Leandro Batista")`

`Backend Example:`

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("FromFormExample")]
        [ActionName("FromFormExample")]
        public ActionResult<RequestMode> FromFormExample([FromForm]RequestMode model)
        {
            return model;
        }
```

**FromBody Example:**

`Client Side Example:`

```cs
<h2>From Body</h2>

@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function (e) {
                $.ajax("https://localhost:44346/api/ConnectUs/FromBodyExample", {
                    method: "post",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        MpnID: 5,
                        PartnerName: "Leandro Batista"
                    }),
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $("#MpnID").text(data.mpnID);
                        $("#PartnerName").text(data.partnerName);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}

<table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr><th>MpnID:</th><td id="MpnID"></td></tr>
    <tr><th>PartnerName:</th><td id="PartnerName"></td></tr>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

> **Note:** Here you should remember data should be in `JSON.stringify` format and content type should be `contentType: "application/json"`

`Backend Example:`

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("FromBodyExample")]
    [ActionName("FromBodyExample")]
    public ActionResult<RequestModel> FromBodyExample([FromBody]RequestModel model)
    {
        return model;
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Hopefully, this would diminish confusions . Still if you any further question feel free to let me know.

Comment: This wasn't what I asked tho, I said that when I send it to the webservice AFTER receiving it from a form it doesn't work, totally different. 
I CAN post it to my controller, the problem is when it goes from my controller to another service.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, in that case you need to `Serialize` that because `FormData` keeps data into key-value pairs. I tried to shown you both format. Let me know if you require any further assistance.

Comment: Yep, I Serialized my model but it didn't work.
I don't know if the webservice needs to change to get a FormData request or something like that

Comment: Would you kindly share your code snippet where you did serialized. So that I can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one i also faced same problem when trying to get List with FormData using [FromForm].

**[FromForm] method:**

```
[HttpPost("create")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([FromForm]CreateRequest createRequest)
```

```
     List<ListModel> listModel = new List<ListModel>();
     foreach (var data in HttpContext.Request.Form.Keys.Select((val, i) => new { key = val, intIndex = i }))
     {
         if (data.key.ToLower().Equals(nameof(createRequest.ABC).ToLower())) 
         {
             var contextData = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HttpContext.Request.Form[data.key]) ? HttpContext.Request.Form[data.key] : new Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues();
              var value = "[" + contextData + "]";
              listModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ListModel >>(value);
          }
      }
```